# How can I SELECT DISTINCT on one (excluded) column, but include other columns in the query? (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have data arranged loosely like this:

Table 1 - PEOPLE: person_id (primary key), parent_id, child_id, other_parent_fields, other_child_fields

Table 2 - PARENTS: parent_id (auto incrementing primary key), other_fields
Table 3 - CHILDREN: child_id (auto incrementing primary key), parent_id(foreign key referencing PARENTS) other_fields

I want to be able to query for all of the distinct parents from the PEOPLE table, and insert all of the other_parent_fields into the PARENTS table, throwing out the old parent_id from Table 1, in favor of my auto incrementing parent_id in table 2.

I also want to do the same for children, but maintain the parent-child relationships, only using my own ids from table 2 and table 3.

Essentially, I am trying to change the way that the database is designed. Rather than a whole table for all people, I am creating a PARENTS table and a CHILDREN table, the latter of which refers to PARENTS with a foreign key. The reason I am throwing out the ids from table 1 is because I have no reason to care about them in my new table (i.e. the numbering can start back from one, and additional entries can just auto increment the primary key). However, before discarding these IDs from table 1, I need to capture the parent-child relations that they relay.

Is this even possible? How would one go about doing it?

we can assume, for simplicity that no children have children i.e. someone cant be a parent and a child

Comment: Does this have to be sql only? Can you write an application that interfaces to do this? Or must you use pl/sql?

Comment: i think I would first build temporary tables similar to your new tables but with the addition of a column to hold the old id, and use this to reference back to the old data, should make the queries simpiler.

Answer (score 2):

I did not fully understand your question but it seems that you first query would be this (SQL Server syntax):

```
insert into Parents
select other_parent_fields, person_id as legacy_parent_id
from (select distinct person_id, other_parent_fields from PEOPLE where parent_id is null) x
```

The trick would be to first group on parent_id, other_parent_fields and then discard the parent_id. (A distinct is equal to a group by *). The above query only works if other_parent_fields is a pure function of parent_id. I interpret your question as an attempt to normalize denormalized data, so I guess this is true.

In order to extract the children you can do this:

```
insert into Children
select other_child_fields, parent_id as legacy_parent_id
from (select distinct person_id, other_child_fields from PEOPLE where parent_id is not null) x
```

Now your tables contain the distinct parents and children as well as their old IDs. You have to write an update query now that assigns the new parent ids into the children table. Then you drop the legacy fields.

Comment: I have added a paragraph of clarification in the original question.

Comment: I have modified the original query and added the missing one.

Comment: does the x on the end of the first sql statement do anything? or is that a typo?

Comment: The x is the name of the derived table. It is required to give it a name on sql server. The x makes it shut up.

Comment: I prefer to use in clauses and nested queries versus the distinct keyword.  Distinct should be avoided as it's a cover up for writing a bad query.  This applies to both SQL and Oracle.   You can read the following link for more information as to why....  http://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/07/24/the-effects-of-distinct-in-a-sql-query/

Comment: This question deals with a legacy data model. This is a one-time query which converts from the old to the new model. Your concerns do not apply here.